# Stretch a div based on its content

Tags: javascript, css, html, stretch

I have a select list and a div in a page. content of the div is depended on the list selected item and it is filled using javascript. I want div to stretch accordion to its content I don't mean the scrollbar,I mean changing in width and height of the div.

should I use javascript for doing it or it is possible using CSS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergey says, you can just set display: inline on the div to achieve this.

```
div{
  display: inline;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qf9a8/